# Getting fixture not found in pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am getting following error while running pytest using following code im unable to figure out whats wrong please find below code snippets.

**Console ouput :**

```
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.2.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: D:\Workspace\AutomationProject, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.6.1, allure-pytest-2.5.5
collected 1 item

tests\pages\test.py E                                                                                            [100%]

======================================================= ERRORS ========================================================
__________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test.test_test ___________________________________________
file D:\Workspace\AutomationProject\tests\pages\test.py, line 5
      def test_test(self):
E       fixture 'web_driver' not found
>       available fixtures: _UnitTestCase__pytest_class_setup, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, cov, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, no_cover, pytestconfig, record_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

D:\Workspace\AutomationProject\tests\pages\test.py:5
=============================================== 1 error in 0.12 seconds ===============================================
```

My Base class contains following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest
import unittest

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def web_driver(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver.exe")
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    web_driver.close()


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("web_driver")
class Base(unittest.TestCase):
    '''
    This fixture contains the set up and tear down code for each test.

    '''
    pass
```

and test class contains following code:

```
from core.web.Base import Base

class test(Base):

    def test_test(self):
        self.driver.get("http://google.com")
```

The test fixture is web_driver still getting error not found !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`web_driver()` is defined outside `Base` class scope, so it's invisible to the `usefixtures` as it is part of `test` class scope. You could [move it to conftest file](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session), but IMHO a better solution is to move `web_driver` inside `Base`

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("web_driver")
class Base(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def web_driver(self, request):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver.exe")
        request.cls.driver = driver
        yield
        driver.close()
```

As a side note, it should be `driver.close()`, not `web_driver.close()`

Comment: Solution worked but why cant we use outside the class it in same file it ?

Comment: @user1323a Updated my answer.

Comment: when Im running tests using this fixture when extending base class in two classes and trying to run test im getting error :Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'   but when running single class it runs fine is it a base class issue ?

Comment: @user1323a You run the tests in parallel? If you do it's expected, you need to use some parallelism mechanize (like Selenium Grid for example)

Comment: issue gets resolved when i comment out driver.close line and it runs. I think problem is it driver gets closed and then the call is made to driver but how can i achive this without commenting out the driver.close becouse it uses same driver for all the tests how can i open browser for every test i tried changing scope

Comment: @user1323a I couldn't reproduce. Open a new question with the code of the base class and the tests you are trying to run, it's hard to solve this in the comments.

Comment: The link "move it to conftest file" ist oudatet (section does not exist in the document linked)

Comment: @yankee updated, thanks.